Add product name in stripe invoice.payment_succeeded event
We are using salesforce connector to connect stripe and salesforce.
All the webhook events are captured properly in salesforce and once such event we are using is invoice.payment_succeeded
              "product": "prod_PjY8saXZSU4b",
              "nickname": null,
              "metadata": {},
              "lookup_key": null,
              "livemode": false,
              "custom_unit_amount": null,
              "currency": "usd",
              "created": 1719826948,
              "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
              "active": true,
              "object": "price",
              "id": "price_1PXgkiH7y1vTRsp1KGus2gRw"
            "metadata": {},
            "livemode": false,
            "invoice": "in_1PquSDDDTRsp1Yu2KXT0b",
            "discounts": [],
            "discountable": true,
            "discount_amounts": [],
            "currency": "usd",
            "amount_excluding_tax": 152600,
            "amount": 152600,
            "object": "line_item",
            "id": "il_1PquZpH7y1vTSDCCuvYIkWJG"

We are getting the above JSON in the web hook event. We are getting the product id but we need product name also added in the event.
With the product Id I can make a call to get the name but thinking that I can reduce one API call if I get the Product name in the response.
I am not able to find any seetings to add the name in the web hook event.

Unfortunately, you can't configure/choose which attributes to be sent to you in an event. I'm not sure what you want the product description for exactly but sometimes it's good to rely on the lines.data.description[0] instead.
